# Where can I learn about implicit UI functions of SE?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I recently noticed that clicking the vote score shows you the up and down votes:

[image: before] (click) [image: after]

Where could I have learned this?

What other tricks exist?

Comment: The usual places: http://english.stackexchange.com/faq in the section on reputation, you get that ability at 1000 rep which you must have recently gotten.

Comment: Actually you should have gotten a notification about unlocking this. Not sure how soon these are generated, though. You might have to wait for a day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comes with the "[established user](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user)" privilege, which you will receive at 1000 rep (congrats on receiving it).

I am going to list many special features. You might already know of some of them.

Another privilege that few know of is "[view close votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes)", which comes at 250 rep. It allows you to see close votes on your own questions. You can also now [create gallery chat rooms](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms). Read the [privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/) page to view more of these.

<del>Type `@` into the search box. It gives you a list of [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=@).</del> ***New:*** Search for anything in the search box and expand the Advanced Search Tips *on the right.* Although "Advanced Search Tips" isn't as cool as "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options", you'll get the same functions. These are particularly helpful for finding duplicates or related posts. They also come in handy for finding stats.

Click <kbd>review</kbd> at the top of the screen. Click any one of the <kbd>recent reviews</kbd> buttons. Then, hover over the progress bar below the <kbd>ask question</kbd> button. It will give you stats on badge progress such as total review in that queue, number of votes cast, number of votes cast on questions, and number of edits performed. It shows how close you are to each of the respective badges.

There are also many secret [comment formatting markdowns](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). These include `[meta]` to link to meta, `[sitename.se]` to link to that site (e.g., `[english.se]`, and `[FAQ#section_number]` to link to that section of the FAQ (e.g., `[FAQ#2]`).

Comment: you need a second upvote for the `<kbd>` syntax!

Comment: That in itself could probably be added to this list! It took me forever to find out about it.

Comment: I didn't know about the [sitename.se] shorthand – thanks!